# mean and standard deviation report in a paper

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, reporting

Basically, mean and standard deviation are reported as `mean ± std` in papers. But it often bugs me because the standard deviation is sometimes so big that, say, `mean+3std` makes no sense:

[image]

This is an example of some muscle timing activation relative to some anatomical event. Whatever the meaning of those muscles, `-0.382 + 3 * 0.289 = 0.485` make no sense for that muscle as it would activate too late. So, is there somme rules to interpret that or it depends on the field ?

Comment: You appear to impose some criterion for "making sense" that has little meaning in general.  What would be special about the mean plus three SDs?  Why not add 30 SDs or a googolplex SDs and compare that to something?

Comment: This is to express some extreme value. But indeed, there is no reason to choose 3 SD. I meant that the underlying gaussian allows value that cannot always make sense regarding the muscle.

Comment: But you can report a mean and SD without assuming a Gaussian distribution. Most distributions have means and SDs. (Also: using an observed mean and SD, and sample size, you can calculate the standard error of the mean, and the sample mean *is* [asymptotically] normally distributed.)